# Upload a (zip) file to a JSON api with Python

Tags: python, json, file

I need to upload a zip file to an ISAM appliance with python. I tried a lot of things, but nothing seems to work.

My current code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# import libraries
import urllib
import urllib2
import base64
import json
import yaml


headers = {  'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 'Accept' : 'application/json','User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)' }

datafile = open('/path/tofile/file.zip', 'rb')

b64_text = base64.b64encode(datafile.read())

values = { 'file': b64_text }

json_data = json.dumps(values)

req = urllib2.Request('https://hostname/reverseproxy/instance/management_root', json_data, headers)
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ('user', 'password')).replace('\n', '')
req.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % base64string)
req.get_method = lambda: 'POST'
try:
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    data = f.read()
    print data
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e
```

The error that I get back from the webservice is:

```
HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed
```

The IBM documentation about the function I am using can be found [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.isam.doc_70/ameb_webseal_appl_guide/task/tsk_lmi_webserv_doc_root_imp_zip.html)

Comment: Does not seem to be ZIP related because all you do with the zip file is read it, encode the contents in base64, and wrap that in a json dict.  _Then_ you upload that arbitrary string via HTTP and get the error.  Have you tried (just for testing) whether that works with a small test value, e. g. `json_data = 'test123'`?

Comment: @Alfe I get the same error 'HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed'

Comment: So, your problem is not connected to ZIP at all ;-)  Maybe you want to reduce the code to a minimal display which still has the error.  It could be authentication related.  I propose to ask a new question after you found out what really is the issue here, with new title, new keywords, so people will find your question.

Comment: Even better: First use `curl`, as all the examples in the linked docs do, to get it to work. Then you can compare what it's sending vs. what your code is sending on the same (minimal) example (e.g., by pointing them at a local netcat server instead of the ISAM, or putting a proxy in the way, or Wiresharking, or whatever you prefer), and then you can work backward from the differences.